# Can't get cifs to mount network drive during boot using fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to get a network share to mount on startup using cifs. I can get the share to mount after linux boots, but for some reason I can't get it to work when editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

Here's the line that works after the system boots

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=password //mycloud/drive//media/drive`

Here's the line in the fstab file

`//mycloud/drive /media/drive  cifs username=user,password=password,_netdev`

Comment: Unmount it and add the output of `mount -a` as `root` to your question.

Comment: When I send `sudo mount -a` to the terminal the drive gets mounted as expected, no errors in the terminal.

Comment: Does anything appear during boot? Add the contents of `/var/log/boot.log` during the last boot.

Comment: I dont have a boot.log file, but I do have a syslog file

Comment: looks like im getting this error `cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101`

Comment: I think that the network is coming online after the mount is attempted. I thought that the `_netdev` option was supposed to make the mount occur after the network comes online

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that `cifs` doesn't use `_netdev` so I found this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124673 which uses `x-systemd.automount` instead